# SDK location not found and failed to load command fastlane

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-studio, sdk

I try to build react-native app on Mac. I installed Java, android studio etc.. have this issue:
`bundler: failed to load command: fastlane and SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file.`
I created a file local.properties and set there `sdk.dir = /Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk`
but after I run command that builds app, this file disapears. and still we have this issue:

`Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.\nUse '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.\`

Comment: Mac or windows?

Comment: mac @RahulKumar

Answer (score -2):

I found this link it may solve the issue
these are the steps: 
Run this from cmd line:
ANDROID_HOME="C:\Users\1mike12\AppData\Local\Android\sdk" react-native run-android
if still no,
create a local.properties file in the root of your projects directory and add in:
sdk.dir=C:\Users\1mike12\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
reference:
https://medium.com/@selvakumar_P/sdk-location-not-found-f7bdf13dc09